# Invalid property value for rainbow border: CSS

Tags: css, colors, linear-gradients

On the website, there is a long blue tail. For pride month, I wanted to change this tail to rainbow. The original CSS code is the following:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #101625;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #375778;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16,22,37,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16,22,37,1);
}
```

Originally, when I was mocking up how the tail would look, I would inspect the source of the website, and add the following code to the above. It would then work and change the tail to be rainbow:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #101625;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #375778;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16,22,37,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16,22,37,1);background-color: #101625;
border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
border-top: 0px solid transparent;
border-left: 0px;
border-right: 0px;
border-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet, red);
border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

I recognize now there is some repeat code, but this solution was working. However, when I went to update the real CSS style sheet, the changes weren't implemented. Inspecting the source revealed that there were invalid property values. I tried to correct the code to the following, but nothing changed:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #101625;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #375778;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16,22,37,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16,22,37,1);
    border-bottom-width: 15px solid; 
    border-bottom-style: transparent;
    border-image-repeat: linear-gradient( 45deg, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet, red);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Any bit of help would be appreciated.

[image: Pasted in code in source viewer that works]

[image: CSS Code with invalid property values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```css
.site-header {
   background-color: #101625;
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 999;
   border-bottom: 15px solid #375778;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16, 22, 37, 1);
   box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(16, 22, 37, 1);
   border-bottom-width: 15px solid;
   border-bottom-style: transparent;
   border-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet, red);
   border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header"></div>
```

Comment: @Neioo Glad to help. Also please click the gray checkmark next to my answer to help new people in Stack Overflow. :)